# How do I select an image from an array of images and draw the image on the canvas

Tags: javascript, drawing, p5.js

I have encountered a problem with this project I'm working on. The code here is to draw an image anytime the mouse is clicked on the canvas. I have an array of country flags and I want to let the user select any flag of their choice and draw it on the canvas. When I click on the option to select any flag of my choice from the canvas, it only draws one particular flag. I want someone to help me find a way to select different flags from the array and draw them on the canvas.

[image: canvas]

```
for(var i = 0; i < 254; i++){
    flags[i] = loadImage('assets/flags/a' + i + '.png');
}

this.fla = flags[i];

//where was the mouse on the last time draw was called.
//set it to -1 to begin with
var startMouseX = -1;
var startMouseY = -1;

this.draw = function(){
    //if moused is pressed draw selected object at mouse locations on the canvas
    if(mouseIsPressed){
        //checks the size of the stamp object
        var starSize = this.starSizeSlider.value();
        var starX = mouseX - starSize/2;
        var starY = mouseY - starSize/2;

        for(var i = 0; i < flags.length; i++){
            if(this.selectionToolForOptions.selected()== flags[i]){
                image(flags[i], starX, starY, starSize, starSize);
               
            }
            else if (this.selectionToolForOptions.selected()=='cloud'){
                image(this.flag, starX, starY, starSize, starSize);
            }
        }
       
    }
}

//when the tool is deselected just show the drawing and and clear the options
this.unselectedTool = function() {
    select("#sizeOfControl").html("");
}

//add options to select type of object to be selected and size the objects
this.populateOptions = function() {   
    this.textProperty = createDiv('Size: ');    
    this.textProperty.parent('#sizeOfControl');
    this.starSizeSlider = createSlider(5,80,10);
    this.starSizeSlider.parent("#sizeOfControl");
    this.optionTextProperty = createDiv('Options: ');
    this.optionTextProperty.parent("#sizeOfControl");
    this.selectCountryFlag = createSelect('Star: ');
    this.selectionToolForOptions = createSelect();
    this.selectionToolForOptions.parent("#sizeOfControl");

    for(var i = 0; i < flags.length; i++){
        this.selectionToolForOptions.option(flags[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue appears to be that you're specifying an object (a `p5.Image` instance) as the name of the options you are creating. Both the name and the value for select options must be strings. Because when `p5.Image` is converted to a string it is `"[object Object]"` all of your select options are the same.

Here's a simple working example.

```js
let imgs;

function preload() {
  imgs = {
    "option A": loadImage("https://www.paulwheeler.us/files/existing-content.png"),
    "option B": loadImage("https://www.paulwheeler.us/files/new-content.png")
  };
}

let imgSelect;
function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  imgSelect = createSelect();
  for (const key in imgs) {
    imgSelect.option(key);
  }
  
  imgSelect.position(10, 10);
  background(220);
}

function draw() {
  if (mouseIsPressed) {
    image(imgs[imgSelect.value()], mouseX, mouseY);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/p5.js"></script>
```